Gaussian quadrature degree of precision on arbitrary interval
Consider the quadrature $I_{n}(f)=w_{1}f(x_{1})+w_{2}f(x_{2})+\ldots +w_{n}f(x_{n})$ for approximating the integral $I(f)= \int_{-1}^{1}f(x) \,dx$.
Prove that for any choices of distinct real numbers $x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n} \in \left[a,b\right]$ the degree of precision of $I_{n}(f)$ is at most $2n-1$.
What I could do was this:
If $x_{1},x_{2},\ldots x_{n}$ are zeros of Legendre polynomial of degree $n$ in the interval $[-1,1]$, then the degree of precision of $I_{n}(f)$ is at most $2n-1$ by considering $\int_{-1}^{1}\psi_{n}^{2} \,dx=\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_{i}\psi^{2}(x_{i})$.Right side is $0$ but left side is not.

Depending on the context of the task, your outline could be too short as you jump directly to the optimal case. Otherwise the idea is correct.

I saw a proof in this video that was a little more general in that the $x_n$ could be any $n$ distinct numbers, even complex. Let $I_n(f)=\sum_{i=1}^nw_if(x_i).$
Also let $\pi_n(x)=\prod_{i=1}^n(x-x_i)$ and $\pi_n^*(x)=\prod_{i=1}^n(x-x_i^*)$
Then $\int_{-1}^1\pi_n(x)\pi_n^*(x)dx=\int_{-1}^1\left|\pi_n(x)\right|^2dx\gt0$. But since for each sample point $x_i$, $\pi_n(x_i)=0$,
$\sum_{i=1}^nw_i\pi_n(x_i)\pi_n^*(x_i)=0$.
